# How to change chrome driver path without closing chrome?

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to change chrome download folder path without closing the chrome?

```
Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
bot.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "c:\temp"
bot.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
bot.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
bot.Get "http://google.com"
bot.Quit
```

Comment: This line `bot.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "c:\temp"` should do the work. What error you are facing?

Comment: Hello, @NandanA

I was trying to do like below

``Dim bot As New ChromeDriver``
``Dim j As Long``

``lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row``

For J = 2 to lastrow
``bot.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "c:\temp"``
``bot.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True``
``bot.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False``
``bot.Get "http://google.com"``

``bot.getelement to download``

Next J
``End Sub`` 

in the next j chrome path should change but it was not changing

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are little bit confused about chrome browser download folder location and chrome driver download location.

**Chrome browser**:

- You have Chrome browser in your machine and let's say its download folder location is `C:/Download/`
- If you run your selenium script to download some file by default the chrome driver will use download location as `C:/Download/`

**Chrome driver**:

- In your code, you changed the default location from `C:/Download/` to `C:/Custom/` by using `download.default_directory` preference then the files be downloaded to the new location.
- Changing of download file location is applicable for chrome **driver** only not for chrome **browser**. Your chrome browser default location stays as `C:/Download/`

In below example, I downloaded a file by changing the download folder location.

**Code**:

```
Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
bot.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "C:\Users\Nandan\Desktop"    
bot.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True  
bot.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False    
bot.Get "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=700&sc_lang=en"    
bot.FindElementByLinkText("Export to Excel").Click    
bot.Timeouts.Server = 5000   
End Sub
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I think OP's question was how to change `c:\temp` at runtime.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for your response. Isn't changing download location preference before launching driver is called runtime?

Comment: _before launching_ -> Compile time (possible), _while program is in execution_ -> Runtime (not possible) as the settings are already baked within the profile settings.

Comment: Thank you but as per my knowledge there is no way to change driver preferences at Runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are right !!!

Comment: Thank you @Nandan but I was running for loop function I want to change the download path after the first loop was done.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: @JacksonJerold why do you want change download path inside loop? Just change it before launching the driver.